# Room database custom fuction

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to retrieve from the database, a list of data that is in a distance interval in ascending order, and i want it to be directly from the sql query. I used these two methods

```
(place_address_latitude - :pLatitude)*(place_address_latitude - :pLatitude) + ((place_address_longitude - :pLongitude)*(place_address_longitude - :pLongitude)) AS distance
```

and

```
ABS(place_address_latitude - :pLatitude) + ABS(place_address_longitude - :pLongitude)
```

but the result is not exactly as I want it. It is very important that the distance calculation is in the sql query, because the result is DataSource.Factory because i'm using the pagination library.

Is there any way to add a custom function to Room to calculate the distance using Location.distanceBetween (...) method? It is important that the method is compatible with Room.

Comment: can you please paste your DAO interface

Comment: for this query I used a RawQuery.

this is the method that build the RawQuery :
https://image.ibb.co/iZgM8K/Croquis.png

and this is the method in the DAO :
https://image.ibb.co/gP5yoK/Croquis1.png